# How to create a json from an parent-child relation in Python

Tags: python, json

I've a table like data with parent-child relationship. Developed a small chunk of code to loop over all children, if there are sub child, it goes through all sub elements.
This is the code;

```py
data_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id':           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'parent_id':    [0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4],
        'name': ['assetX', 'assetY', 'assetZ', 'assetQ', 'assetW', 'assetM', 'assetN', 'assetH']
    }
)
def get_children(data_df,parent_id):
    print("parent:"+str(parent_id))
    children_df = data_df.loc[data_df['parent_id'] == parent_id]
    children = children_df['id'].tolist()
    print children
    for child in children:
        print "child:"+str(child)
        get_children(data_df,child)       

parent_id=0
get_children(data_df,parent_id)
```

---

I would like to create a json like below out of it;

```
{
  "assets": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "assetX",
      "assets": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "assetZ",
          "assets": [
            {
              "id": "5",
              "name": "assetW",
              "assets": []
            },
            {
              "id": "6",
              "name": "assetM",
              "assets": []
            },
            {
              "id": "7",
              "name": "assetM",
              "assets": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "assetQ",
          "assets": [
            {
              "id": "8",
              "name": "assetH",
              "assets": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "assetY",
      "assets": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Again, the main challenge is I don't know how many sub items I'll have.
Is there any advise?

Comment: main problem is you haven't explained your output. what is it supposed to mean? you have shown in your expected result that `"assetA"` and `"assetB"` has same id and parent id and you nested it but none of them exist in your example. Try to explain logic with related output to your inputs

Comment: I've cleaned the output a bit.

Comment: @code_ada, is there a reason my answer is not an accepted one?

Comment: just did @TarunLalwani, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursion is your friend here

```
def get_childrens(df, parent_id):
    data = df[df["parent_id"] == parent_id].apply(lambda row: {"id": row["id"],
          "name": row["name"],
          "assets": []}, axis=1)
    data_list = data.tolist() if not data.empty else []
    for i, d in enumerate(data_list):
        d["assets"] = get_childrens(df, d['id'])
    return data_list
```

and then

```
import json
print(json.dumps({"assets": get_childrens(df, 0)}, indent=2))
```

The output is as expected

[image: Output]